# Azure Function Python - Using Chrome Driver - Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, azure, selenium, azure-functions

I am attempting to use the Chrome Driver with Selenium in Azure Functions (Python 3.8) and the chrome driver that was downloaded via a Python script and shows `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`.

Selenium version 4.3.0

Chrome Driver version used [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver_linux64.zip).

The Chrome browser was also downloaded to the same path and extracted (downloaded [here](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1034863%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media)).

Selenium Options

```
chromedriverpath = "/tmp/HttpTrigger_Helper/chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") # overcome limited resource problems
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # bypass OS security model
chrome_options.binary_location = "/tmp/HttpTrigger_Helper/chrome-linux/chrome" # Chrome Browser File Location
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriverpath, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Is there something else that needs to be installed or configured?

```
Result: Failure Exception: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /tmp/HttpTrigger_Helper/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace: #0 0x556ca1396403 <unknown> #1 0x556ca119c778 <unknown> #2 0x556ca11c0fa9 <unknown> #3 0x556ca11bc12b <unknown> #4 0x556ca11f783a <unknown> #5 0x556ca11f18f3 <unknown> #6 0x556ca11c70d8 <unknown> #7 0x556ca11c8205 <unknown> #8 0x556ca13dde3d <unknown> #9 0x556ca13e0db6 <unknown> #10 0x556ca13c713e <unknown> #11 0x556ca13e19b5 <unknown> #12 0x556ca13bb970 <unknown> #13 0x556ca13fe228 <unknown> #14 0x556ca13fe3bf <unknown> #15 0x556ca1418abe <unknown> #16 0x7f7760970ea7 <unknown>
```

Comment: Chrome version? ChromeDriver version?? Selenium version???

Comment: Chrome and driver versions are the links present in the post. @undetectedSelenium